# Python Clicker for 2 Players

Tags: python

I created a clicker game for two players in Python and I have a little problem..

When the game starts, player one's turn is not being counted in the variable active_player, and then starts to count with player two button 's'. This problem is resolved by adding variable update_display() to player one's click in def click():, and to player 2 in def click_s(): variable, and the problem is the messages (labels) about bonuses disappear after this counter fixer.

**Attach two codes **
**first**: with fixed counter ,but without player labels,
**Second**: without counter, but fixed labels for players

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

1. **Without labels about players bonuses but fixed counter(update_display())**

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

bomb = [100, 100]  
score = [0, 0]     
active_player = 0  
press_return = False
dynamite_explosion = False
bomb_freeze_duration = 3500
bonus_active = False
bonus_freeze_time = 500 

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Clicker Game')
root.geometry('600x600+500+100')
root.resizable(False, False)

label = tk.Label(root, text='Press Enter to start the game...',
                 font=('Comic Sans MS', 16))
label.pack()

fuse_label = tk.Label(root, text=f'Fuse: {bomb[active_player]}', font=('Comic Sans MS', 17))
fuse_label.pack()

score_label = tk.Label(root, text=f'Score - Player 1: {score[0]} | Player 2: {score[1]}',
                       font=('Comic Sans MS', 17))
score_label.pack()

img_1 = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/1.gif')
img_2 = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/2.gif')
img_3 = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/3.gif')
img_4 = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/4.gif')
img_5 = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/Png.gif')
img_6 = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/trap_2.png')
img_7 = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/xp.png')

bomb_label = tk.Label(image=img_1)
bomb_label.pack()

def update_display():
    fuse_label.config(text=f'Fuse: {bomb[active_player]}')
    score_label.config(text=f'Score - Player 1: {score[0]} | Player 2: {score[1]}')

    if bomb[active_player] == 0:
        label.config(text=f"Player {active_player + 1}: Game Over! Press Enter to restart.")
    else:
        label.config(text=f'Player {active_player + 1}: Game in progress...')

    if active_player == 1:
        click_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    else:
        click_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

def is_alive():
    return bomb[active_player] > 0

def update_bomb():
    global dynamite_explosion
    if is_alive():
        bomb[active_player] -= 3
        if bomb[active_player] <= 0:
            bomb[active_player] = 0
            bomb_label.config(image=img_4)
        elif bomb[active_player] <= 25:
            bomb_label.config(image=img_3)
        elif bomb[active_player] <= 50:
            bomb_label.config(image=img_2)
        else:
            bomb_label.config(image=img_1)
        update_display()
    elif dynamite_explosion:
        label.config(text=f"Player {active_player + 1}: Game Over! Press Enter to restart.")
        bomb_label.config(image=img_4)

def update_score():
    global active_player, score
    if is_alive():
        score[active_player] += 1
        update_display()

def dynamite_explosion_message():
    global dynamite_explosion
    dynamite_explosion = True
    click_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    label.config(text=f'Player {active_player + 1}: BOOM! Trap-Dynamite exploded! Score reset to 0')
    root.after(bomb_freeze_duration, reset_dynamite_explosion)

def reset_dynamite_explosion():
    global dynamite_explosion
    dynamite_explosion = False
    click_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

def apply_bonus():
    global score
    bonus_type = random.choice(['xp', 'double xp', 'dynamite'])

    if bonus_type == 'xp':
        apply_xp_bonus()
    elif bonus_type == 'double xp':
        apply_double_xp_bonus()
    elif bonus_type == 'dynamite':
        apply_dynamite_bonus()
    else:
        update_display()
        update_bomb()

def apply_xp_bonus():
    global score, bonus_active
    bonus_amount = random.randint(1, 25)
    score[active_player] += bonus_amount
    label.config(text=f'Player {active_player + 1}: You received {bonus_amount} XP bonus!')
    bomb_label.config(image=img_7)
    bonus_active = True
    click_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    root.after(bonus_freeze_time, reset_bonus)

def apply_double_xp_bonus():
    global score, bonus_active
    bonus_amount = random.randint(1, 75)
    score[active_player] *= 2
    label.config(text=f'Player {active_player + 1}: You received double XP bonus! Score doubled!')
    bomb_label.config(image=img_5)
    bonus_active = True
    click_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    root.after(bonus_freeze_time, reset_bonus)

def reset_bonus():
    global bonus_active
    bonus_active = False
    click_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

def apply_dynamite_bonus():
    global score
    score[active_player] = 0
    bomb_label.config(image=img_6)
    dynamite_explosion_message()

def start(event):
    global bomb, score, press_return, dynamite_explosion, active_player

    if not press_return:
        press_return = True
        label.config(text=f'Player {active_player + 1}: Game in progress...')
        if active_player == 0:
            click_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        else:
            root.bind('S', click_s) 
            click_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    elif bomb[active_player] == 0:
        active_player = (active_player + 1) % 2
        restart_game()

def restart_game():
    global bomb, score, press_return, dynamite_explosion, active_player, bonus_active
    bomb = [100, 100]
    score = [0, 0]
    press_return = False
    dynamite_explosion = False
    bonus_active = False 
    fuse_label.config(text=f'Fuse: {bomb[active_player]}')
    score_label.config(text=f'Score - Player 1: {score[0]} | Player 2: {score[1]}')
    bomb_label.config(image=img_1)
    label.config(text=f'Players, Press Enter to restart the game...')
    click_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    root.unbind('s')  
    
def click():
    global press_return, active_player, bonus_active
    if press_return and is_alive() and active_player == 0 and not bonus_active:
        update_score()
        update_bomb()
        if random.random() < 0.1:
            apply_bonus()
        active_player = (active_player + 1) % 2
        update_display()

def click_s(event):
    global press_return, active_player, bonus_active
    if press_return and is_alive() and active_player == 1 and not bonus_active:
        update_score()
        update_bomb()
        if random.random() < 0.1:
            apply_bonus()
        active_player = (active_player + 1) % 2
        update_display()

click_button = tk.Button(root, text='Click me!',
                         bg='black', fg='white',
                         width=20, font=('Comic Sans MS', 17, "bold"),
                         command=click, state=tk.DISABLED)
click_button.pack()
root.bind('<Return>', start)
root.bind('s', click_s)
root.mainloop()
```

**broken counter, but fixed labels for players**

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

bomb = [100, 100]  
score = [0, 0]     
active_player = 0 
press_return = False
dynamite_explosion = False
bomb_freeze_duration = 3500
bonus_active = False
bonus_freeze_time = 500 

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Clicker Game')
root.geometry('600x600+500+100')
root.resizable(False, False)

label = tk.Label(root, text='Press Enter to start the game...',
                 font=('Comic Sans MS', 16))
label.pack()

fuse_label = tk.Label(root, text=f'Fuse: {bomb[active_player]}', font=('Comic Sans MS', 17))
fuse_label.pack()

score_label = tk.Label(root, text=f'Score - Player 1: {score[0]} | Player 2: {score[1]}',
                       font=('Comic Sans MS', 17))
score_label.pack()

img_1 = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/1.gif')
img_2 = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/2.gif')
img_3 = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/3.gif')
img_4 = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/4.gif')
img_5 = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/Png.gif')
img_6 = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/trap_2.png')
img_7 = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/xp.png')

bomb_label = tk.Label(image=img_1)
bomb_label.pack()

def update_display():
    fuse_label.config(text=f'Fuse: {bomb[active_player]}')
    score_label.config(text=f'Score - Player 1: {score[0]} | Player 2: {score[1]}')

    if bomb[active_player] == 0:
        label.config(text=f"Player {active_player + 1}: Game Over! Press Enter to restart.")
    else:
        label.config(text=f'Player {active_player + 1}: Game in progress...')

    if active_player == 0:
        click_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    else:
        click_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

def is_alive():
    return bomb[active_player] > 0

def update_bomb():
    global dynamite_explosion
    if is_alive():
        bomb[active_player] -= 3
        if bomb[active_player] <= 0:
            bomb[active_player] = 0
            bomb_label.config(image=img_4)
        elif bomb[active_player] <= 25:
            bomb_label.config(image=img_3)
        elif bomb[active_player] <= 50:
            bomb_label.config(image=img_2)
        else:
            bomb_label.config(image=img_1)
        update_display()
    elif dynamite_explosion:
        label.config(text=f"Player {active_player + 1}: Game Over! Press Enter to restart.")
        bomb_label.config(image=img_4)

def update_score():
    global active_player, score
    if is_alive():
        score[active_player] += 1
        update_display()

def dynamite_explosion_message():
    global dynamite_explosion
    dynamite_explosion = True
    click_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    label.config(text=f'Player {active_player + 1}: BOOM! Trap-Dynamite exploded! Score reset to 0')
    root.after(bomb_freeze_duration, reset_dynamite_explosion)

def reset_dynamite_explosion():
    global dynamite_explosion
    dynamite_explosion = False
    click_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

def apply_bonus():
    global score
    bonus_type = random.choice(['xp', 'double xp', 'dynamite'])

    if bonus_type == 'xp':
        apply_xp_bonus()
    elif bonus_type == 'double xp':
        apply_double_xp_bonus()
    elif bonus_type == 'dynamite':
        apply_dynamite_bonus()
    else:
        update_display()
        update_bomb()

def apply_xp_bonus():
    global score, bonus_active
    bonus_amount = random.randint(1, 25)
    score[active_player] += bonus_amount
    label.config(text=f'Player {active_player + 1}: You received {bonus_amount} XP bonus!')
    bomb_label.config(image=img_7)
    bonus_active = True
    click_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    root.after(bonus_freeze_time, reset_bonus)

def apply_double_xp_bonus():
    global score, bonus_active
    bonus_amount = random.randint(1, 75)
    score[active_player] *= 2
    label.config(text=f'Player {active_player + 1}: You received double XP bonus! Score doubled!')
    bomb_label.config(image=img_5)
    bonus_active = True
    click_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    root.after(bonus_freeze_time, reset_bonus)

def reset_bonus():
    global bonus_active
    bonus_active = False
    click_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

def apply_dynamite_bonus():
    global score
    score[active_player] = 0
    bomb_label.config(image=img_6)
    dynamite_explosion_message()

def start(event):
    global bomb, score, press_return, dynamite_explosion, active_player

    if not press_return:
        press_return = True
        label.config(text=f'Player {active_player + 1}: Game in progress...')
        if active_player == 0:
            click_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        else:
            root.bind('S', click_s)  # Гравець 2 може нажимати клавішу 'S'
            click_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    elif bomb[active_player] == 0:
        active_player = (active_player + 1) % 2
        restart_game()

def restart_game():
    global bomb, score, press_return, dynamite_explosion, active_player, bonus_active
    bomb = [100, 100]
    score = [0, 0]
    press_return = False
    dynamite_explosion = False
    bonus_active = False  # Reset bonus activation
    fuse_label.config(text=f'Fuse: {bomb[active_player]}')
    score_label.config(text=f'Score - Player 1: {score[0]} | Player 2: {score[1]}')
    bomb_label.config(image=img_1)
    label.config(text=f'Players, Press Enter to restart the game...')
    click_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    root.unbind('s')  # Stop listening for the 'S' key
    
def click():
    global press_return, active_player, bonus_active
    if press_return and is_alive() and active_player == 0 and not bonus_active:
        update_score()
        update_bomb()
        if random.random() < 0.1:
            apply_bonus()
        active_player = (active_player + 1) % 2

def click_s(event):
    global press_return, active_player, bonus_active
    if press_return and is_alive() and active_player == 1 and not bonus_active:
        update_score()
        update_bomb()
        if random.random() < 0.1:
            apply_bonus()
        active_player = (active_player + 1) % 2

click_button = tk.Button(root, text='Click me!',
                         bg='black', fg='white',
                         width=20, font=('Comic Sans MS', 17, "bold"),
                         command=click, state=tk.DISABLED)
click_button.pack()
root.bind('<Return>', start)
root.bind('s', click_s)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is very difficult to help you since we cannot run your code (e.g. we don't have any file named 'images/1.gif' on our computer). Try to reduce your code step by step while still reproducing the error, then we can help you better.